# Redirect root and root only BUT not root with extra parameters /?param=foo

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using the following script in my htaccess to redirect ROOT and ROOT ONLY, which works fine.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://shop.mydomain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

BUT, I've run into problems where my blog, which is still running under mydomain.com, still needs to access root with extra parameters for the search results etc.

Is there a way to still display those pages?

e.g. mydomain.com redirects but mydomain.com/?s=foo does not redirect.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more condition to make sure this redirect works only when query string is not present:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
Rewriterule ^/?$ http://shop.mydomain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Awesome, that's working! I noticed you omitted the line "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$"... it's not necessary?

Comment: Yes that line is not necessary because RewriteRule is doing same thing now.